# how to use Almofirwe framework for rest api calling?

Tags: ios, alamofire

I used the below code to call rest api using `Alamofire` framework.

```
func getHomeList()
{        
    let userId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "user_id")!

    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "my_id" : "\(userId)",
        "flage" : "1"
    ]


    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    ]


    Alamofire.request(URL(string: "\(Constants.webApi)\(Constants.gethistory)")!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

        self.arrList = NSMutableArray()

        if let followers = response.result.value as? NSDictionary
        {
            print(followers)

            if let status: Int = followers.object(forKey: "status") as? Int
            {

                if status == 1
                {

                    if let arrData: NSMutableArray = followers.object(forKey: "data") as? NSMutableArray
                    {

                        self.arrList  = arrData

                    }

                }
                else
                {

                    let message = MessageView.viewFromNib(layout: .MessageViewIOS8)
                    message.configureTheme(.info)
                    message.configureDropShadow()
                    message.configureContent(title: "Sorry", body: "Something went wrong. Please Try Again")

                    var messageConfig = SwiftMessages.Config()
                    messageConfig.presentationStyle = .bottom
                    messageConfig.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindowLevelNormal)
                    messageConfig.duration = .automatic

                    SwiftMessages.show(config: messageConfig, view: message)

                }

                self.tblList.reloadData()

            }

        }
    })

    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

But I don't know how I am not getting response in api and how to check if network is reachable or not.

Also how to handle if request is not successfully done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check request success or fail using below code snippet

```
Alamofire.request("your URL", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

    switch(response.result) {
    case .success(_):
        if let data = response.result.value{
            print(response.result.value)
        }
        break

    case .failure(_):
        print(response.result.error)
        break

    }
}
```